Can struct fuse_session be transferred between two unrelated process?
Using libfuse3.16.2 lowlevel_api mode
I have got two process A and B
A:
fuse_session_new
fuse_session_mount
fuse_session_loop_mt

SIGHUP action:
fuse_session_exit stop the mt loop
sendmsg to B (send se-\>fd to B)

B:
wait on recvmsg
get session fd
fuse_session_new
fuse_session_set_fd (se-\>fd = fd)
fuse_session_loop_mt

Although program B has restarted the loop as imagined, any operation related to the file system will become Input/output error.
Is there a way for B to perfectly inherit A's fuse_session and block requests on/dev/fuse during runtime ?
I have a file system client program implemented based on the libfuse library, now I need to support its hot upgrade feature. During the upgrade period, the customer's IO cannot be interrupted, so I tried to pause for now the fuse_session_loop_mt and transfer the /dev/fuse fd to another process to simulate the upgrade process, but it didn't work as mentioned above. Is my original plan not feasible or is there another way? Any help would be very appreciated!

You must verify that: 1. fd wasn't closed nor set to -1 on first mount going down. 2. fd wasn't overridden by a fresh open of the mount point on second mount going up.

Yes, 1. I didn't call fuse_session_unmount in A after the fuse_session_exit, and I checked that the fd got by fuse_session_fd was not -1 before sendmsg to B. 2. I did't call fuse_session_mount in B after recvmsg received the fd from A, and checked it not -1 too.

Well, you can try get some clue about what's going on using lsof -p <your program PID>, look at /dev/fuse opens before and after the mount switch.

OK, when A was running fuse_session_loop_mt, the lsof command get
A 46654 root    5u   CHR             10,229      0t0        792 /dev/fuse
when A exit the loop, I lsof B got:
B 46947 root    4u   CHR             10,229      0t0        792 /dev/fuse
but with warnning error:
[root@hb13-udisk-29-20 ~]# lsof -p 46947
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.zyf_test1 file system /mnt/zyf_test
Output information may be incomplete.

And the libfuse debug log shows: fuse: writing device: Invalid argument, I located that it was in fuse_lowlevel.c : fuse_send_msg:writev(ch ? ch->fd : se->fd, iov, count), the se->fd seemed that has expired.
